# concave curve in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

How can we draw a concave curve like the following one without having any numeric data?

[image]

Comment: `\draw (0,2) to[out=0,in=90] (3,0);`

Comment: Looks like a quarter of an ellipse to me. Try something like: `\draw (0,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=90, x radius=1cm, y radius=5mm];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, drawing without numerical data might be impossible.

### Without PSTricks:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (2,0) arc [x radius=2, y radius=1, start angle=0, end angle=90];% or the old, deprecated, less verbose version \draw (2,0) arc (0:90:2 and 1);
    \draw (-.1,0) -- (2.1,0);
    \draw (0,-.1) -- (0,1.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### With PSTricks:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-.1,-.1)(2.1,1.1)
    \psellipticarc(0,0)(2,1){0}{90}
    \psline(-.1,0)(2.1,0)
    \psline(0,-.1)(0,1.1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]