# fill in the blank between two curves and arrow which shows the change

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

In continue to my previous question, [concave curve in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120791/concave-curve-in-tikz?noredirect=1#comment269425_120791), I would like to know how can I achieve the yellow area of the next figure and the little arrow in it? I don't care about how small the arrow would be, but I'd like its appearance in my figure.
[image]

My code so far is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=100pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,3) to[out=0,in=90] (3,0);
    \draw[->, very thick] (-.1,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw[->, very thick] (0,-.1) -- (0,5);
\draw[green] (0,4) to [out=0, in=90] (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `border=100pt` is extremely too huge so it makes the output look less proportional.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10):

### Without PSTricks:

No need to use `++`!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=yellow] (2,0) arc (0:90:2) -- (0,1.5) arc (90:0:1.5) -- cycle;
    \draw[->] (-.3,0) -- (2.3,0);
    \draw[->] (0,-.3) -- (0,2.3);
    \draw[->] (45:1.5) -- (45:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### With PSTricks:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-.3,-.3)(2.3,2.3)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow]
    {
        \psarc(0,0){2}{0}{90}
        \psline(0,2)(0,1.5)
        \psarcn(0,0){1.5}{90}{0}
        \closepath
    }
    \psline{->}(-.3,0)(2.3,0)
    \psline{->}(0,-.3)(0,2.3)
    \psline{->}(1.5;45)(2;45)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're a TikZpert!

Comment: I used `++` to highlight how length and position can be speficied separately.

Answer (score 6):

You can draw two filled paths, one inside the other, to create the yellow shape.
The arrow can be easily added using the polar notation `(deg:len)`.

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=100pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[yellow] (0,4) to [out=0, in=90] (4,0) -- (0,0); %outer
  \fill[white] (0,3) to[out=0,in=90] (3,0) -- (0,0);    %inner
  \draw[->, very thick] (-.1,0) -- (5,0);
  \draw[->, very thick] (0,-.1) -- (0,5);
  \draw[->, very thick] (45:3) -- ++(45:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: I took the liberty of adding the result! Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Nice. However, it might be better to draw the shape using a single path, instead of drawing a white shape on top. That way, things in the background (like a grid, for instance), can still be seen. You could do this using `\fill[yellow] (0,4) to [out=0, in=90] (4,0) -- 
   (3,0) to[out=90,in=0] (0,3) -- cycle;`, for example.